# Oracle Entity Framework causes form shrink in 4K monitor

Tags: oracle, winforms, entity-framework

I am using Oracle managed driver and Entity 5x.  I have a winforms VB project and am seeing the strangest thing.  When the data source of the Binding Source is filled, then the form shrinks about 50%, on a 4K monitor.  Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```vb
            db = New RadsEntityConnStr4() ' entity context
            db.SetDatabase()

            If (mViewAddEdit = ViewAddEditEnum.Add) Then
                Me.bsPhantom.AddNew()
                Return
            End If
```

```
        Dim query = From ps In db.PHANTOM_SESSION Where (ps.PHNTM_SESSION_NO = CDbl(mPhntmSessionNum))
        bsPhantom.DataSource = query.ToList() ' resize occurs here
```

Comment: Is the WinForm app declared DPI Aware? May be issue similar to [When clicking “btnLogin”, my forms decrease in size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48272782/2592875).

Comment: See also the notes here: [DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50276714/7444103).

Comment: Yes, this one solved it.  Turning the app to DPI aware fixed it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272782/when-clicking-btnlogin-my-forms-decrease-in-size